# Black screen after starting Ubuntu

Tags: boot

have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on laptop packardBell EasyNote TK
Processor  Intel Celeron T3500
Screen   15.6"  16:9 HD LED LCD

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Try starting Ubuntu with the following kernel parameters: `nomodeset, noquiet, nosplash`

Check this link if you need help settings the parameters (boot options): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#GRUB

`nomodeset` is most important.  It makes the kernel wait to initialize some video settings and use the more dependable but less capable BIOS video mode.  This was described previously [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

`noquiet` and `nosplash` just turn off the splash screen so you can hopefully see the ugly startup text scroll by and catch any other possible reason for your issues.